# jQuery load() and Spring 3 MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

How can Spring 3 MVC receive the JSON data posted by jQuery `load()`? It seams to revive it. Can anyone help me? When I use `@Responseboy`, it works.

Comment: yes i think we can do it ,writing append is so painful, I am testing http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/ and will inform you if success,but the problem is to integrate with parameters gathering and post

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get JSON data from spring mvc, you should use $.getJSON method of jquery.